# Configure TV Capture card to not use external audio jack for TV audio output

Tags: ubuntu, audio, mythtv, hauppauge

I had this working with MythTV on Ubuntu 9.1. Then a power surge killed the motherboard. After replacing the motherboard, ram and cpu, the card does not produce any audio except through the output jack on the back of the card.

I do not want to use a cable to go from the back of the card to the audio in on the built in sound card of the new mother board.

FYI, the old motherboard did not have an on-board sound card. There was a separate audio card installed.

There's some configuration that has to be done to have it work the same way again. I just have no idea where to start.

This is regarding wintv hauppauge mythtv linux ubuntu 9.10 audio

Answer (score 1):

I believe the thing you are looking for is a kernel module called btaudio:
http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Btaudio

This routes audio over the pci bus instead of out the sound port. I hope that wiki article is enough to get you going, it sounds like you have done it before.